# Zeus IDE autocomplete option for Golang (intellisense macros missing)

Tags: autocomplete, zeus

I have installed Zeus IDE v397 to run, compile and debug Golang scripts successfully as i work on win32 platform. The new version v398 of Zeus is for win64 ONLY because i can not open it!

> I would like to ask you how can i set up the autocomplete feature on
>   the editor as i have got a small problem there and only that feature
>   is missing from me. I saw that several macros such as 
>   go_intellisense_dot.py, go_intellisense.py and others intellisense are
>   missing. How can i find and install them successfully to my
>   Zeus IDE?

Additionally i would like to tell you that Zeus IDE is a great tool with a lot of features especially when i do Golang scripting.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of the Zeus IDE.

The 3.97z version of Zeus was the last one to run on Windows XP and the newer 3.98 versions require Windows Vista or better.

Another big difference between those version is the fact that the embedded Python engine moved from version 2.7x to 3.52 so the scripts are not interchangeable.

To help you out I have uploaded the last set of Zeus Python 2.7x Go macros to here: http://www.zeusedit.com/z300/go_scripts.zip

Now I can't guarantee these will work with that 3.97z version, since that is such an old version, but there is a good chance they might.

If you run into any issues feel free to raise an issue on the Zeus forum.